# Can a blocked thread wake itself?

Tags: java, multithreading

Thread A

```
synchronized void methodA() throws Exception {
    wait();
}

synchronized void methodB() {
    notify():
}
```

Thread B

```
//... work
A.methodB();    // thread A was so far blocked by calling wait()
```

In a scenario like this, can a thread that is blocked wake itself?

Comment: Might just be me, but i'm not totally getting the question. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: if thread A is sleeping and thread B wakes thread A up, it's not clear why do you ask if a thread can wake it self up. BTW the answer is no.

Comment: @CollinD - The problem is that no MCVE is possible for this question.  What the OP is (facially) trying to do is not expressible in Java ... or any other imperative programming language.  (I hesitate to say no PL at all, because their could conceivably be a computation model with this would be possible ... and that model could conceivably be implementable, say on a quantum processor.)

Comment: A blocked thread can't do *anything.* It is blocked. Not executing. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a blocked thread wake itself?

Nope.

A thread that is blocked in `wait()` (or any other blocking call) cannot execute any code until it unblocked.

Doing anything ... including calling `notify()` ... requires the thread to already be unblocked.

---

If your design requires precisely this, it is unimplementable.  Here are a couple of ideas ... though neither does exactly what you are asking.

1. Instead of `wait()` use a timed wait; e.g. `wait(millis)`.  That will wait for a notify (from another thread!) or until `millis` milliseconds have elapse ... whichever happens first.
2. Use a second thread to `notify()` the first one.